# REGEX for two sets of numbers with a dash between them; can't start with a 0

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, expression

As the title says I'm looking for a regex to provide the following. Using Asp.net regular expression valiator.

I need to validate a range of x-y.

The numbers for x and y can't start with 0.

The numbers for x and y can be 1 digit to 6 digits in length.

No other characters other than numbers and one dash between them allowed.

Value of x can't be a lower value than y or equal to y. (probably have to check this another way)

Here are examples of what should pass and fail:

```
0-252 > fail
1-252 > pass
9823-10000 > pass
10-3 > fail
12345 > fail
498 8987 > fail
0023-002343 > fail
1234567-1234567 > fail
123456-123457 > pass
2-10-233 > fail
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Value of x can't be a lower value than y or equal to y. (probably have to check this another way)

Exactly. You should better validate this without regex. For the rest of the condition, you can use this regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,5}-[1-9][0-9]{0,5}$
```

Comment: Fantastic! Now why didn't I come up with that? So simple. Thanks!